# Can you compile a LINQ to Entities query that is composed with if statements?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a fairly complex LINQ to Entities query I'd like to try compiling because it's a bit slower than I'd like.

I build it in a series of steps though. Here's a simple example:

```
public static List<Employee> GetEmployees(EntityContext ctx, bool showTerminated)
{
    var q = ctx.Employees;

    if(showTerminated==false)
    {
        q = q.Where(e => e.TerminationDt == null);
    }

    //...more conditional filters / Group By / Select applied...

    return q.ToList();
}
```

Is there any way to take advantage of compiled queries when you have this type of conditional query composition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. However, you could rewrite the query into a compilable version:

```
var q = ctx.Employees.Where(e => showTerminated || !e.TerminationDt.HasValue);
// rest of method
```

Comment: var q = ctx.Employees.Where(e => !showTerminated || !e.TerminationDt.HasValue);